# Объединение моделей в Django

Tags: django

Есть две модели. Первая - это набор неких предметов и их характеристики. Вторая - это название группы и 4 предмета из первой модел. Как их связать вместе? Пытался через `ForeignKey`, но в коде, приведённом ниже могу добавить только 1 один предмет с первой модели во вторую. Если просто добавить 4 идентичных строки по типу итем(1-4) и продублировать `models.ForeignKey(Upgrades, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`, то при миграции выдает ошибку, что место зарезервировано. Что нужно изменить, чтобы заработало.

```
class Upgrades(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=34)
    gold_for_sale = models.IntegerField()
    gold_for_update = models.IntegerField()
    exp_for_update = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class UpgradesSets(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    upd_sets = models.ForeignKey(Upgrades, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

upd
Вроде исправил, вчера сонный писал вышло немного сумбурно.

Comment: Как вариант - использовать сигнал. Какие поля должны быть во второй моделе?

Comment: У второй моделе должно бить только название и 4 элемента 1 модели. 1 модель как тут выступает как набор работников, а другая это группы по 4 человека составленные с этих работников. При чем эти работники могут и будут одновременно задействованы в нескольких таких группах.

Comment: @Dezilok, а где сама модель работника? Непонятно

Comment: @Александр про работники был чисто пример, который работает на 100% как приведено выше. Просто вместо работников набор предметов, которые по такому же принципу должны формировать группы.Только сейчас перечитал сообщение в главном посте, его изменило.

Comment: @Dezilok просто ваши поля совсем не отображают вашу задумку. Первое, что приходит в голову - добавить 4 foreign key на 1ю модель, но без каскадного удаления. Relative_name прописать

Comment: @Александр спасибо Relative_name помогло, каскадное удаление пришлось оставлять. Поскольку on_delete= параметр теперь обязательный для ForeignKey, но он проблем не вызывал.